# dreamweaver and mysql help

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

I am new to dreamweaver cs4 and am trying to do some basic functionality.  I have followed an online tutorial which showed me how to create a template.dwt file and include some editable regions in the file.  Then to create HTML and PHP files based on the template which let me put data in the various editable regions.

I want to take this a step further and show data from a MySQL DB on a page.  I have created a connection to the MySQL server and tested it okay.  I have created a recordset and am at the point where I cant see how to display the recordset on a page in an editable region.  If anyone has any ideas or has any tutorials online that they can point me towards that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't a free online tutorial the book series "The Missing Manual" is actually very detailed with Dreamweaver.

Comment: thanks for your response, i was hoping for an online tutorial but will certainly look at that resource.